# TestNG - Instance variable in test class gets overwritten while trying to execute test cases in parallel="methods" mode

Tags: parallel-processing, testng, instance-variables

I have written below testNG test class.

```
import org.testng.annotations.*;

@Test
public class Dummy_001 {
    String temp;

    public void test_1(){
         temp = "Sample 1";
        System.out.println(temp);
    }


    public void test_2(){
        temp = "Sample 2";
        System.out.println(temp);
    }

    public void test_3(){
        String temp = "Sample 3";
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}
```

I am executing the test with an xml file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Exercise Suite" parallel="methods"  thread-count="3">
    <test name="Lambda Test Exercise 1">       
        <classes>
        <class name="ui.Dummy_001">
        <methods>
            <include name="test_1"/>
            <include name="test_2"/>
            <include name="test_3"/>
        </methods>
        </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I am expecting to have the `temp` to have method specific values during the parallel execution.
In actual execution I am getting an output as follows.
[image: Execution Screenshot]

Is this an expected behavior. If yes then is there any way to prevent the instance variables gets overwritten by different threads and to have different instance variables to each thread.